# Extended NEWS and Partials is not rendering

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

I use an extension that extended NEWS.

This my setup for my template file

```
plugin.tx_news {
view {
    event {
        templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/news/events/Templates
        partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/news/events/Partials
    }
}}
```

The action is EventList and the template fileadmin/templates/news/events/Templates/EventList.html rendering is Ok.

In that template I call a partial with

```
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
    <f:debug>{newsItem}</f:debug>
    <f:render partial="Eventlist/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
</f:for>
```

The f:debug give my news.

The file fileadmin/templates/news/events/Partials/EventList/Item.html exists.

Any thoughts about that.

TYPO3 7.6.29
NEWS 6.1.1

Comment: EventList vs Eventlist, L vs l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two anotations to your **setup** typoscript template:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    view {
        event {
            // use *Paths (plural) with a higher number
            // but maybe you meant constants, then the singular is alright
            templateRootPaths.10 = fileadmin/templates/news/events/Templates
            partialRootPaths.10 = fileadmin/templates/news/events/Partials
        }
    // never ever!!!! try to close multiple brackets in one line
    // TYPO3 recognizes only brackets at the beginning of a line
    // sidenote: the same for multiline comments: 
    //           '/*' and '*/' only at the beginning of a line
    }
}
```

---

As georg already commented: your bug probably is the correct spelling of `EventList` in the path of your partial.

You might get more error information by switching into develop mode (Installtool) and configure in your typoscript setup:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```